# Customize ADFS SignIn Page using Querystring parameter

Tags: asp.net, adfs2.0

I know I can customize the signin page in the adfs\ls folder.
But inside that FormsSignIn.aspx page or master page I want to use a querystring parameter.
But HttpContext.Current.Request.Querystring is empty.
Any idea?
What I want to achieve is to make the layout dependend on a querystring parameter or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why it is empty but there are other ways to do this. Off the top of my head :-)

- Request.RawUrl
- Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"]
- Request.Params[""]

Does one of these work?

Comment: RawUrl shows the url with the querystring. But ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"] returns empty. So could decode RawUrl, but why is the querystring not provided by ASP.NET? Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the query string is not available using the "standard" property. I'm using this in my code:

```
NameValueCollection queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);

if (queryString.AllKeys.Contains("param"))
{
    string value = queryString["param"];
}
```